# JavaScript multidimensional array check duplicate

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a simple way to check whether the values in a multidimensional array is duplicated in JavaScript.

Actually, I have a form with multiple inputs for Currency, Rate and Amount
And I would like to call a JavaScript function to check before submit the form.

Here is the array

```
Array(
    [0] => Array("CNY","2","1000")
    [1] => Array("EUR","5","1200")
    [2] => Array("USD","3","900")
    [3] => Array("USD","8","1500")
    [4] => Array("EUR","5","1200")
)
```

My purpose is to check the row cannot be exactly the same.

In my case, [1] => Array("EUR","5","1200") and [4] => Array("EUR","5","1200") is duplicate.

At the end, Key [1] and [4] will be returned by the function.

I will be glad if someone can give me some advice.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function, it returns an array of keys of the values having duplicates in the containing array:

```
function find_keys_of_dupl(a){
    var k = [];
    for(var i in a){
        for(var j in a){
            if(i!=j && JSON.stringify(a[i]) == JSON.stringify(a[j])){
                if(k.indexOf(i) < 0){
                    k.push(i);
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    return k;
}

var a = [["CNY","2","1000"],["EUR","5","1200"],["USD","3","900"],["USD","8","1500"],["EUR","5","1200"]];
console.log(find_keys_of_dupl(a));
```

Output:

```
["1", "4"]
```

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/r0kk0nuk/